# I need help identifying an old strange tool

Tags: cast-iron

It's the tool in the foreground, not the distributor machine in the background. It's got a heavy cast iron base. The gear thing on the right seems to index to each tooth. There are many other pulley and brackets that came with it. But other than that I have no idea what it is.

[image: old tool]

Comment: You might have better luck getting a definitive answer over at owwm.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's difficult to be precise with pieces missing but the overall structure points to this being a Straightline Engine Turning Machine. Just last week, I watched a [video showing one in use](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IoNK8wVz63Q). Fully manually operated, turning wheels that make slides move, adjusting other wheels with indexing pawls and a follower/template combination that provides for variation in depth of cut in a dynamic manner.

The video description uses the word Guilloche which a search indicates that it's the type of pattern generated by the machine and clearly shown in the video.

There are similarities to what is likely a different brand name machine [image: straight line machine]visible at [goldmachinery web site](https://goldmachinery.com/machinery/0347.htm).

Comment: Neat video.  Too bad those videos don't mention the twenty years of practice to make that job look easy to do by hand.

Answer (score 0):

In German it would be called "Frezer" (no clue in English). Probably metal milling machine.

It is used for metal processing like making trenches, or surface work.

The wheel on the bottom right would slide the top table longitudinal.

The top (round) table is not meant to be turned during processing, it is locked in a position of choice.